# mariaDB not caching queries cached by mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mariadb, query-cache

I'm migrating my database (MySQL 5.1.73) to a new server, and I am trying to replace it with mariadb (5.5.5-10). Globally mariadb seems much faster, but there is a couple of queries that it refuses to cache where mysql does.
This is a big problem because those queries are used LOTS (there are sort of on the home page so will be executed pretty much every time the user interact).

I thought mariadb was a drop in replacement for mysql, so I'm surprised of this behavior ? As anyone any idea why such a different behavior or how can I force the cache to be used (I tried `SELECT SQL_CACHE` but that doesn't change anything.

Here is the mysql configuration

```
    +------------------------------+------------+
    | Variable_name                | Value      |
    +------------------------------+------------+
    | binlog_cache_size            | 32768      |
    | have_query_cache             | YES        |
    | key_cache_age_threshold      | 300        |
    | key_cache_block_size         | 1024       |
    | key_cache_division_limit     | 100        |
    | max_binlog_cache_size        | 4294963200 |
    | query_cache_limit            | 1048576    |
    | query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096       |
    | query_cache_size             | 16777216   |
    | query_cache_type             | ON         |
    | query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF        |
    | table_definition_cache       | 256        |
    | table_open_cache             | 64         |
    | thread_cache_size            | 8          |
    +------------------------------+------------+
```

And the mariadb one

```
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                  | Value                |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| aria_pagecache_age_threshold   | 300                  |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size     | 134217728            |
| aria_pagecache_division_limit  | 100                  |
| aria_pagecache_file_hash_size  | 512                  |
| binlog_cache_size              | 32768                |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size         | 32768                |
| have_query_cache               | YES                  |
| host_cache_size                | 228                  |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache | OFF                  |
| innodb_ft_cache_size           | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit   | 2000000000           |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size     | 640000000            |
| join_cache_level               | 2                    |
| key_cache_age_threshold        | 300                  |
| key_cache_block_size           | 1024                 |
| key_cache_division_limit       | 100                  |
| key_cache_file_hash_size       | 512                  |
| key_cache_segments             | 0                    |
| max_binlog_cache_size          | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size     | 18446744073709547520 |
| metadata_locks_cache_size      | 1024                 |
| query_cache_limit              | 1048576              |
| query_cache_min_res_unit       | 4096                 |
| query_cache_size               | 16777216             |
| query_cache_strip_comments     | OFF                  |
| query_cache_type               | ON                   |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate   | OFF                  |
| stored_program_cache           | 256                  |
| table_definition_cache         | 400                  |
| table_open_cache               | 400                  |
| thread_cache_size              | 100                  |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: If you want to know what's in query cache, MariaDB has a plugin for that https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/query_cache_info-plugin/ . 5.5.5-10 is not a real version, it is a trick to workaround the bug in MySQL replication (long story) . I think the version is 10.0.something. 'SELECT @@version' gives you real one.

Comment: If the database name has any special characters and the engine is InnoDB, the QC won't work in older versions of MySQL.  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55556

Answer (score 1):

There are many different "caches"; not all of them have 'cache' in their name.  The most important is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  An that one is important only if you are using `InnoDB` (which you should be) instead of MyISAM.  Furthermore, was the Engine of individual tables changed during the upgrade?

Check the table Engines and buffer_pool_size, then report back.  BTW, the buffer_pool should be about 70% of *available* ram.  And show us the non-cached queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for them.

I see that the Query cache is set the same way.  However, that is *usually* bad for an active production server.  But that is another topic.

"Drop in replacement" -- mostly it is.  But, as you found out, it is "faster" in some ways, "slower" in others.  Even if you moved from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5, you might see similar better/worse scenarios.

Comment: Nothing has been changed during the upgrade. I'm using docker to switch between mysql and mariadb and start with the same dump. However I tried mariadb 10 and I don't have this problem anymore, or not for some queries.